# Splitting a string that has numbers and characters into an int and String

Tags: java

I have a String that goes "Peyton Manning; 49". Is there a way to have the computer read the left side of the String and make it equal to a new String "Peyton Manning" and take the right side of the String and make it equal to an int with a value of 49?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you're asking. Can you clarify what do you mean by "left side" and "right side"? Are all your strings formatted in the sme way?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear wording. What I mean by this is that I want to read the String "Peyton Manning; 49", and then make "Peyton Manning" into a string and give an int the value of 49. Please let me know if I am still being unclear so that i can further elaborate if needed.

Comment: I think you have an answer to your question? Can you please mark it correct, if it's what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

A number of ways spring to mind: you can tokenize or you can use regexs. You didn't specify about white space padding. Also, you didn't specify if the string segments around the delimiter can be invalid integers, mixtures strings digits etc.

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="Blah; 99";

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ";");
        String name = st.nextToken();
        Integer number = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().trim());
        System.out.println(name.trim() + "---" + number);

        number = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        name = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
        System.out.println(name + "---" + number);

        int split = s.indexOf(";");
        name = s.substring(0, split);
        number = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(split+2, s.length()));
        System.out.println(name + "---" + number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is:

```
String text = input.replaceAll(" *\\d*", "");
int number = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

See [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).